# characters received in serial communication only after pressing enter

Tags: serial

I have a simple PC to board connection using serial (9600, no parity, 8 bits, no hw flow) I opened simple terminal *with teraterm) in PC and enter keys in teraterm and in board, I just do

```
 cat /dev/tty05
```

I see the pressed characters in scope, but I see the characters in the board console, only after pressing "enter" in teraterm (as if they are stored in some FIFO in Linux driver which only enter triggers out)

why are the characters received in Linux driver only when pressing enter key ?
Is there some way to receive the characters without pressing the enter key ? (we use some protocol of ascii so it does not make sense to send this as dummy)
Thanks for advise, 
Ran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cat` program is using line buffering.  This is why you don't see the results until the key is pressed.  The terminal driver is seeing the characters as they arrive, but `cat` is not displaying them.  Instead of using cat, try using a terminal emulator to see the characters arriving.

The terminal is likely also in `cooked` morde.  You can disable this by running the command `stty raw < /dev/tty05` before you run cat.  You can reset the setting with the command `stty sane < /dev/tty01`, although it may get reset when you close the terminal.

It is common for programs using the terminal to read characters as they arrive.  Terminal emulators are one of these, and are more appropriate for use in your case.

If you only want to read the data, it is simple to code a blocking character re. ad in most language.  This can be run in a loop echoing the characters as they arrive.

EDIT: The following python script demonstrates reading characters from a terminal device one by one.  This requires the terminal be in raw mode to disable buffering in the terminal driver.  The `stty` command can be used to set the terminal in raw mode, but this program does this.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import termios
import tty
with open('/dev/tty', 'rb') as f:
    fd = f.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    print "Enter characters (q to quit)"
    tty.setraw(fd)
    ch = ''
    try:
        while ch != 'q':
            ch = f.read(1)
            if not ch:
                print "End of file"
                break
            print "Read a character:", ch, '\r'
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get same result in code too (I see print only after enter), why ?

  unsigned char myarray[10] = {0};
  int fd; 
  int n = 0;
  int rc = 0;
  int flags;
  fd = open(FPGA_SERIAL, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
    perror("Unable to open serial");
  }
  else
  {
      flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
      flags = 0;
      fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags);
  }
  tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
  while(1)
  {
        n = read(fd, myarray, 1);
        {
            printf("0x%x\n",myarray[0]);
        }
        continue;
  }
  rc = close(fd);
  return NULL;

Comment: @ransh I've added a python program which reads characters from a terminal.  It is setup to run from the terminal.  If it breaks it can leave the terminal in raw mode, which can be undone by the command `reset`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Bill,
It seems you directed me to the answer. It is related to "line buffering", also termed canonical/non-canonical mode, i.e. also code of reading from uart can support or not support "line buffering":

> ```
>    In canonical mode:
> ```

```
   * Input is made available line by line.  An input line is available
     when one of the line delimiters is typed (NL, EOL, EOL2; or EOF at
     the start of line).  Except in the case of EOF, the line delimiter
     is included in the buffer returned by read(2).

   * Line editing is enabled (ERASE, KILL; and if the IEXTEN flag is
     set: WERASE, REPRINT, LNEXT).  A read(2) returns at most one line
     of input; if the read(2) requested fewer bytes than are available
     in the current line of input, then only as many bytes as requested
     are read, and the remaining characters will be available for a
     future read(2).
```